# Additional TH pad

Tags: pcb, altium

I'm working on a project designed by someone else, when running DRC it gives me hole to hole clearance error, it turns out that there are two TH pads touching one over the other, is there a way to remove one of them from the PCB, or is it a footprint error that should be edited?

[image]

Here's the pad and the error at the bottom of the pic.

Thank you in advance

Comment: To me, that small square-shape hole doesn't seem to be applicable. It's possible to change the pad properties of a component directly on the layout file but if there's two TH pads placed on top of each other then you may need to edit the component in the library, and then update the layout so Altium replaces the old component with newly-edited one.

Comment: Thank u, the square hole is by mistake, I was trying to delete one of the pads and thought by changing shape I might be able to move one of them and forget to put it back to a circle. 
it turned out that the component is from manufacturer library, so it might be that the foortprint is built that way, Can I edit it though?

Comment: Yes, you can edit it in the library, not in the PCB layout file directly.

Comment: Okay, Thank u so much